# Save chat box messages even if you refresh

Tags: javascript, chat

I created this chat box but i don't know why it doesn't save what you submit. So everytime i refresh my page, it goes all clear.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div class="info">
      <label for="example">Enter Text
      </label>
      <input id="example" type="text"
             name="Ntext" size="20">
      <input id="sent" type="submit"  
             value="Send"> 
  </div>
    <p id="para">      
    </p>
  </body>
  <script>
    window.onclick = function(e)
    {   var id =  e.target.id;   
     if (id === 'sent')  
     { var txt = document.getElementById('example').value    
       $( "#para" ).empty().append( txt );
     }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Can I or Do I have to add a save button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data in the DOM (such as the data you are adding using `.append()`) is basically ephemeral and will never stick around after a refresh unless you build out some method for storing and loading it into the DOM yourself. Generally this would look like some sort of server-side database that you wire up to your app through an API you write. Another option for persistence is using `localStorage` (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)).

I would recommend not using `localStorage` for any really important data, though, since it literally keeps data in the user's browser and therefore is not particularly secure, nor does it provide any cross-device persistence at all. But if this is just a toy project and you want to see some data stick around after a refresh, it could do that for you.